# MudBlazor DataGrid Usage on Nested Object Types

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

How would I go about adding a column to a MudBlazor DataGrid that uses a nested object?

For example, I have a basic entity called Foo which has the following makeup:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public Bar Bar {get; set;}
}

public class Bar 
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

How would I add Bar.Name to a column in [MudBlazor's DataGrid](https://mudblazor.com/components/datagrid)?

```
<MudDataGrid Items="@someIEnumerableOfTypeFoo">
    <Columns>
        <Column T="Foo" Field="Id" Title="Id" />
        <Column T="Foo" Field="Bar.Name" /> <!-- This Fails -->
    </Columns>
</MudDataGrid>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the cell template and access the complex object with @context

```
<Column T="Foo">
   <CellTemplate>
      <h1>@context.Item.Bar.Name</h1>
   </CellTemplate>
</Column>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you.  I failed to realize there was a RenderFragment under the Column component that I could work directly with.  If only the pattern of using this was shown in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

It can work if you add the ToString method in Bar like this :

```cs
public class Bar 
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public override string ToString(){
            return Name;
    }
}
```

But it gets more complicated if there is more than one property.

I suggest using MudTable instead of MudDataGrid, DataGrid is an experimental component for now

```html
<MudTable Items="@ListOfFoo" Hover="true" Breakpoint="Breakpoint.Sm">
    <HeaderContent>
        <MudTh>Id</MudTh>
        <MudTh>Name</MudTh>
    </HeaderContent>
    <RowTemplate>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Id">@context.Id</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Name">@context.Bar.Name</MudTd>
    </RowTemplate>
</MudTable>
```

Comment: Good thought on the override of ToString().  I agree though, the DataGrid component still has a bit more to go, especially when working with complex data structures.  I've reported this as an issue in the repo.  If time allows, I'll play around with it some and see what alternative pattern can be applied in lieu of the Field parameter.